# Install kivy Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to install Kivy in python 3.8.3 following all instrucions of kivy page instalation, so when i put this command:

```
python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

The terminal shows me this error:

```
C:\Users\SAGASTUME>python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\sagastume\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (1.25.9)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
   command: 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-eb9bfmtx'
       cwd: C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mqblxk_\kivy\
  Complete output (531 lines):
  Using setuptools
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

  ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\atlas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\cache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\clock.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\context.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\event.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\factory_registers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\geometry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\gesture.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\interactive.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\loader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\logger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\metrics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\multistroke.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\resources.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\support.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\vector.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\weakmethod.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core
  copying kivy\core\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  copying kivy\core\audio\audio_avplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  copying kivy\core\audio\audio_ffpyplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  copying kivy\core\audio\audio_gstplayer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  copying kivy\core\audio\audio_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  copying kivy\core\audio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\audio
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  copying kivy\core\camera\camera_android.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  copying kivy\core\camera\camera_gi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  copying kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  copying kivy\core\camera\camera_picamera.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  copying kivy\core\camera\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\camera
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_android.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_dbusklipper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_dummy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_gtk3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_nspaste.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_sdl2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
  copying kivy\core\clipboard\clipboard_winctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\clipboard
 
  copying kivy\graphics\tesselator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\texture.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\transformation.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\vertex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\common.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\gl_debug_logger.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\img_tools.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\memory.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\opcodes.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\opengl_utils_def.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  copying kivy\graphics\vertex_instructions_line.pxi -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\include
  copying kivy\include\common_subset.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\include
  copying kivy\include\gl2platform.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\include
  copying kivy\include\gl_redirect.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\include
  copying kivy\include\khrplatform.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\include
  copying kivy\lib\vidcore_lite\bcm.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\lib\vidcore_lite
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data
  copying kivy\data\style.kv -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data
  copying kivy\data\settings_kivy.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\DejaVuSans.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\Roboto-Bold.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\Roboto-Italic.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\Roboto-Regular.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  copying kivy\data\fonts\RobotoMono-Regular.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\fonts
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\cursor.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\defaultshape.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\testpattern.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\background.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\image-loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  copying kivy\data\images\defaulttheme.atlas -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\images
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\azerty.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\de.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\de_CH.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\en_US.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\fr_CH.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\qwerty.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  copying kivy\data\keyboards\qwertz.json -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\keyboards
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\data\glsl\default.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\data\glsl\default.vs -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\data\glsl\header.vs -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\data\glsl\default.fs -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\data\glsl\header.fs -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\data\glsl
  copying kivy\tests\unicode_files.zip -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
  copying kivy\tests\unicode_font.zip -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
  copying kivy\tests\testkv.kv -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
  copying kivy\tests\test_button.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
  copying kivy\tests\sample1.ogg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\gles_compat
  copying kivy\tools\gles_compat\gl2.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\gles_compat
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
  copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pep8.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
  copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pep8kivy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
  copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pre-commit.githook -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_bar.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_item.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_item_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_view.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\audio-volume-high.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\audio-volume-low.png -> build\lib.win32
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\sliderv_background_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\slider_cursor.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\slider_cursor_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\spinner.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\spinner_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\spinner_pressed.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_disabled_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_disabled_down_h.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_disabled_h.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\splitter_down_h.png -> build\lib.win32-
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\textinput_disabled_active.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tree_closed.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tree_opened.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_background.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_background.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_key_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
  running build_ext
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
    Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
     command: 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pvid_1bu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\kivy'
         cwd: C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8mqblxk_\kivy\
    Complete output (513 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b'"pkg-config" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,\r\nprograma o archivo por lotes ejecutable.\r\n'

    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\context.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\event.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\factory_registers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\geometry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\gesture.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\core\window\window_egl_rpi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\window
    copying kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\window
    copying kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\window
    copying kivy\core\window\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\core\window
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\deps
    copying kivy\deps\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\deps
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    copying kivy\effects\dampedscroll.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    copying kivy\effects\kinetic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    copying kivy\effects\opacityscroll.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    copying kivy\effects\scroll.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    copying kivy\effects\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\effects
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
    copying kivy\graphics\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend
    copying kivy\graphics\cgl_backend\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\graphics\cgl_backend
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\garden
    copying kivy\garden\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\garden
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input
    copying kivy\input\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\input
    copying kivy\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\test_vector.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\test_video.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\test_widget.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\test_widget_walk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\test_window_info.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\visual_test_label.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    copying kivy\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tests
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\changelog_parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\generate-icons.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\kviewer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\report.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\stub-gl-debug.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\texturecompress.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    copying kivy\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\factory.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks\hook-kivy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks\pyi_rth_kivy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks
    copying kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\packaging\pyinstaller_hooks
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    copying kivy\tools\highlight\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\extras
    copying kivy\extras\highlight.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\extras
    copying kivy\extras\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\extras
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\uix
    copying kivy\uix\accordion.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\uix
    copying kivy\uix\actionbar.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\uix
    copying kivy\uix\anchorlayout.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\uix
    copying kivy\tools\highlight\kivy-mode.el -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    copying kivy\tools\highlight\kivy.json-tmlanguage -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    copying kivy\tools\highlight\kivy.tmLanguage -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    copying kivy\tools\highlight\kivy.vim -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\highlight
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
    copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pep8.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
    copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pep8kivy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
    copying kivy\tools\pep8checker\pre-commit.githook -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\pep8checker
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_bar.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_group_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_item.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_item_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\action_view.png -> build\lib.win32-
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    running build_ext
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAGASTUME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8mqblxk_\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pvid_1bu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\SAGASTUME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

This is part of the error code, because Stack won't let me put all the code because of the character limits, but I think this part shows the most important.

Comment: You probably have, but have you done the previous 2 steps of the installation first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy is not supported still on python 3.8, I use python 3.7, and it's the best version, because PyInstaller works on it, and you can compile for windows, mac, android and ios
So I recommend using it, delete the current version in control panel (if you're on windows) and install [python 3.7.6](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-376/). Remember to add to path when installing of you're on Windows!

Answer (score 0):

C S, I think Kivy is not supported in Python 3.8.x.
But you can try all of these commands(If you are in windows):

```
pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
virtualenv kivy_venv
kivy_venv\Scripts\activate
pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* 
kivy_deps.glew==0.1.*
pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
pip install kivy_deps.angle==0.1.*
pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

If it still does not work downgrade to Python 3.7.x, and try all of the commands again. Even I had the same problem when I had Python 3.8, even I am a kivy programmer, So I downgraded to 3.7 and it worked for me. Try it and hope it works

Happy Python Programming!

Comment: Thanks i used those code and i have the same error :(, i think i'll downgrade python to 3.7 version :)